# JavaFX Application name in Mac Os

Tags: macos, javafx

With Swing apps i've used setProperty() method, but it looks like it doen't work with FX Applications, are there any other ways to configure apps name from source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad news for you.  You can't change it.  Here's a link to the JIRA where you can go and add your disappointment at it not being fixed yet.

https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-22988

Comment: I should add in that this is now possible with one of the latest releases of the jfx:native plugin.  I'm not sure when it was added, but I can now set the application name (and build it for any platform as an app) with http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/native-bundle.html  This does not fix the issue of a plain executable java -jar command, but it's a workaround that's good enough for me.